# Download files from folder in webmatrix

Tags: webmatrix, razorengine

I have a "ticket system" and when the user creates a ticket there is an option to upload files. Those files go to a folder that have the name of the ticket.

This is the code that creates the folder when the  ticket is created.

```
 var nomePasta = "Ticket Id - " + idNovoPedido;
                 string salva =   Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"),"uploadedFiles",nomePasta);
                 Directory.CreateDirectory(salva);
```

Then on the backoffice i can see if there are any files on that folder.

Code to check if there are any files:

```
@foreach (string fullFilePath in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploadedFiles"),"Ticket Id - "+@id)))
                    {
                        <div class="linkFicheiros">
                            <a href="@Href("~/uploadedFiles","Ticket Id - "+@id,Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath))">@Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath)</a>
                        </div>
                    }
```

Now my question is, how can i download the files?

If i click on a link (example if it's a photo, my browser opens a new window and show me the image) and if it's a "docx" it says that "The page cannot be found."

**Update**:

So i've found something, if the file is ".xls" i can download it without any problem, but if the file is ".docx" it gives the error mentioned above "The page cannot be found.".

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other warnings in Internet for the same problem stating that it depends on the lack of definition on the web server for the DocX files' MIME type : [Page cannot be found Error when executing a Hyperlink to a DocX File](http://knowledgebase.triaster.co.uk/help-for-it-administrators/triaster-server/hyperlinktodocxpagecannotbefound).

Anyway, if it could be useful, in this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562101/From-pdf-files-to-plain-text-in-a-WebMatrix-site) I have used a universal routine for the file downloading: [Downloading Files C#](http://dotnetslackers.com/community/blogs/haissam/archive/2007/04/03/Downloading-Files-C_2300_.aspx). You should add the `.docx` case and its MIME type:

> application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document